# $\{\overline{0}\}^{\tau_{1}}$ and $\{\overline{0}\}^{\tau_{2}}$, $\{\overline{n}\}^{\tau_{1}}$ and $\{\overline{n}\}^{\tau_{2}}$

Tags: general-topology

Be $\tau_{1}$ and $\tau_{2}$ topologies over $\mathbb{N}$ defined by:

$\tau_{1}=\{\{m\in \mathbb{N}:m<n\}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{\mathbb{N}\}\}$ and $\tau_{2}=\{A\subseteq \mathbb{N}: 0\in A\}\cup \{\emptyset\}$.

Definition. The closing $\overline{A}$ is defined by the intersection of all closed ones contained in $A$. In other words the $\overline{A}$ is smaller set contained in $A$.

Would you like to know who these sets are? Is it correct what I did?
\begin{equation}
\{\overline{0}\}^{\tau_{1}},\{\overline{0}\}^{\tau_{2}}, \{\overline{n}\}^{\tau_{1}},                    \{\overline{n}\}^{\tau_{2}}
\end{equation}
com $n\in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$.

Before, who are the closed in the $\tau_{1}$ topology and $\tau_{2}$?.

closed $\tau_1=\{\emptyset, \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{N}-\{0\}, \mathbb{N}-\{0,1\}, \mathbb{N}-\{0,1,2\}, \cdots\}$

closed $\tau_2=\{\emptyset, \mathbb{N},\mathbb{N}-\{0\}, \mathbb{N}-\{0,1,18,78\}, \cdots\}$

Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: $\overline{0}^{\tau_1}=\emptyset$.

Comment: @milou The closure of a set at least contains the set itself, so it cannot be empty for a non-empty set..

Answer (score 2):

Every (non-empty) open set in both $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ contains $0$ so the closure of $\{0\}$ in both is $\Bbb N$.

If $n \neq 0$, in $\tau_1$ the closure is $\{m\mid m \ge n\}$ (which is closed and all whose members have minimal neighbourhoods that contain $n$). $\{n\}$ is closed in $\tau_2$ (as its complement contains $0$ and so is open) and so equals its own closure.